# How to remove the scroll bar on the Modal of ant design?

Tags: reactjs, background, modal-dialog, simplemodal, ant-design-pro

How to remove the scroll bar on the Modal of ant design?
Thanks in advance :)
this is my code in modal

````
<Modal
        className='sample'
        visible={sample}
        destroyOnClose={true}

        footer={
          <div className="div-button-save">
          <Button type="default" onClick={() => toggleDialog()}>
          <IntlMessages id="Portal.dialog.button.Cancel" />
          </Button>

         <Button type="primary" onClick={() => handleSave()}>
          <span><IntlMessages id="Portal.dialog.button.Submit" /></span>
          </Button>
          </div>
           }
        maskClosable={false}
        centered>```

[click this picture][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/V8BjX.png
````

Comment: Please share what all you have tried to solve this problem and I would try to help you out further.

Comment: Hi, I updated the question, when the footer is null, there is no scroll but when I add the footer, the scroll bar is appearing

Comment: Could you please include this info within the question?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.